# 'sftp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: sftp

I need to transfer a file from local desktop to a remote unix server using windows command prompt. For this, I'm using `sftp` to connect to the server. I used the command

```
sftp Taps@122.123.124.125
```

However the error I'm getting is

> 'sftp' is not recognized as an internal or external command...

Comment: Are you doing this with Command line?

Comment: Use any sftp client like FileZilla or WinSCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to add the folder where you have put 'sftp' to the PATH environment variable.

Comment: i do have the winscp and putty..what i m trying here is to write a windows command prompt script that will automate the file tranfer process.